# Calculating the probability using Poisson Distribution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, poisson-distribution

> During working hours, an office switchboard receives telephone calls at random and at an average of 3 calls per minute.
>
> a) What is the expected number of calls received during a five minute period?

Ans: Let X = number of calls per minute therefore $\Bbb E[X] = 3$. During a five minute period, $5\,\Bbb E[X] = 15$ expected calls.

> b) What is the probability that exactly the expected no. from (a) are received in a five minute period?

Ans: Let $Y$ = number of calls during a five minute period therefore from the previous question, $\Bbb  E[Y] = 15$.

So, $\Bbb P(Y = 15) = 15^{15}\,\mathsf e^{-15} / 15!$

Are the answers right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.   There is not much more to say.

Comment: Awesome. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

For Poisson Distribution, X=number of occurrences in a time span, $\lambda$=average number of occurrences per unit of time:
$$\mathsf P(X{=}x)~=~\mathsf e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^x/x! \qquad\big[x\in \Bbb N\big]$$
So I believe your answers are correct.